# immutable, updateIn giving invalid keyPath

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am implementing immutable into my redux app and am having issues with the `updateIn` function. I have a toggle that I want to switch on and off with this action, in my reducer. The logic is like so :

```
     case actions.ADMIN_TOGGLE_SETTING:
            console.log("hit toggle", action);
            console.log("state", state.toJS());
            return state.updateIn(['toggleSettings', action.name], (oldValue) => !oldValue);
```

So this gives me a console error of `Uncaught Error: invalid keyPath`. I am not sure why, because that console log that is running the state.toJS() looks like so :

```
{
    toggleSettings : {
        svl : true
    }  
}
```

and the action.name is "svl". So I am thinking maybe the action.name is the problem? but it passes correctly, it looks like so :

```
  {type: "ADMIN_TOGGLE_SETTING", name: "svl" }
```

Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`updateIn` method can only works on immutable.js data structure, so if `Uncaught Error: invalid keyPath` emitted, it is likely that your data structure:

```
{
  svl: true
}
```

is a plain JavaScript object instead of a immutable.js data structure, try convert it using `Immutable.Map`.

Comment: And for some nesting data structure, maybe [Immutable.fromJS](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

like this：`(oldValue=action.name)=>!oldValue`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16881326)

Comment: @JohnMoutafis - please re-review. It does provide an answer, but may not have looked like it before the edit.